# Unable to use sorted() on a list of Model classes

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After running a query on the datastore, I copy the results to a new list as I interrogate, merge and prune the results. When I'm finished, I'd like to sort the new list, but I'm seeing the following error...

TypeError: 'LiveRouteStatus' object is unsubscriptable

LiveRouteStatus is a Model class that I query, and while the actual code is more complicated, here's a shortened version of what I'm doing...

```
class LiveRouteStatus(db.Model):
    dateAdded = db.DateTimeProperty(autho_now_add=True)
    stopID    = db.StringProperty()
    time      = db.IntegerProperty()

q = db.GqlQuery("select * from LiveRouteStatus where stopID = :1 order by dataeAdded desc limit 24", stopID)

route_results = []
for r in routes:
    if magic_test_works:
        route_results.append(r)

sorted(route_results, key=itemgetter('time')
```

Is there some basic element of Python that I'm screwing up here? Or is this an indexing issue with the Model class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itemgetter('time')` is like saying `['time']`.

You want `attrgetter('time')`, which is like `.time`.

Comment: This solved the error... However, it doesn't actually sort. :( Do I need to write my own sort function since it isn't an integer (but rather of type db.IntegerProperty?

Comment: head hanging in shame... i failed to assign the results of the sorted() call.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying LiveRouteStatus and the class you declared is called LiveVehicleStatus.
Not sure if this could be the reason tho !